# How to design watch app screen like Friends app in watch os?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos

I want to create an application with circular menu in dynamic way as like given [here](http://www.apple.com/watch/new-ways-to-connect/). I have tried with lots of efferts but not got success because there are two basic concept for design any watch app like horizonal and vertical what I know as per my learning experience.I want to develope menu which have dynamic menu items. I am not sure it would be possible or not.
It would be great if anyone have any idea.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: That's not a well asked question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution from the apple developer forum. I have implemented above mentioned functionality with the help of this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=216). At the moment, I have developed design with the help of `storyboard` as given in the WWDC video.

Thank You.

Comment: how did you achieve that?

Comment: @ali I have implemented with the help of WkInterfaceGroup. First, I have divided screen with three vertical layouts and each group have its horizontal layout. Currently I have developed watch app with a static menu design. It is hard to explain in this small comments, but I tried my best.